# Create Partioned Table in Postgres Database

Tags: typeorm

Hi as a Postgres Database required that the partition is created with the table I want to supply this with typeorm but haven't found any docs on how to declare this in an entity.
Has anyone already solved this and has an example for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typeorm does not support partition table yet, create partition table in Postgres has to be done with raw query.